# Where does it say that a convert's yetzer hara becomes stronger?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, soul, evil-inclination

I hear this from many authoritative sources but where is it from Torah she beal peh?

Is it merely because all the mitzvot are now obligatory or are there deeper reasons?

Comment: Could you cite some of the sources you heard it from?

Comment: The Talmud says a convert's yetser hara is already stronger, because they are used to things that the frum-from-birth were never exposed to.